# Java SWT Text equivalent to Python Text tagging

Tags: java, python, text, swt, tagging

I wrote an application in Python which used the ScrolledText object. ScrolledText allows one to assign a 'tag' to text which is inserted. For example,

```
tagID = "my tag"

self.scrolledText.insert(location, "The quick brown ....\n", tagID)
```

Assuming each tag you use is unique and assuming the inserted text moves around due to other insertions and deletions, you can always find the location of the text inserted with the tag 'tagID'. For example,

```
start, end = self.scrolledText.tag_nextrange(tagID, "1.0")
```

I now want to rewrite the Python code using Java and SWT, but I see no way to implement this (without a lot of code) in SWT.

My question is: Is there any way to do something similar with java SWT Text or StyledText?

Comment: Almost certain the answer is: No.